# Filter main entity with left join condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables which are **Form**, **Field** and **Type**.
A Form has multiple fields. A field has a Type.

There are 42 types (it's pure coincidence, I swear). A form **always** have 42 fields.

So, now, I display a biiig table with all the forms and fields associated. On top of every column, you can filter the results.

My problem is that I can't find a "simple" way of filtering results.

The only way I managed to achieve this, is by making subqueries, like this :
(on this example, I'm filtering on Type.id = 169 with value "secret")

```
SELECT a.id as fId, f.value, f.type_id
FROM `Form` a
LEFT JOIN Field f ON a.id = f.form_id 
WHERE (
    SELECT `value` FROM Field f2 WHERE f2.form_id = a.id AND f2.type_id = 169
) = 'secret' 
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

It's extreme, because for every filter I add, I have a subquery. So, 10 filters = 10 subqueries.

I think there is a better way of doing this, but I can't figure it out, I hope you can help me understand it !

Thanks !

Comment: If it was me, I'd simplify the problem for the benefit of your poor readers. Let's say, you had 4 fields, and 3 types (or 4 if the number of types is always equal to the number of fields!?!). Now, provide proper DDLs and the desired result set to go with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use additional `JOIN`s

```
SELECT a.id as fId, f.value, f.type_id
FROM `Form` a
LEFT JOIN Field f ON a.id = f.form_id
JOIN Field f2 ON f2.form_id = a.id 
WHERE f2.type_id = 169
AND f2.value = 'secret'
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

If you have more fields to filter on, add additional `JOIN`s for them, and add those conditions to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT a.id as fId, f.value, f.type_id
FROM `Form` a
LEFT JOIN Field f ON a.id = f.form_id
JOIN Field f2 ON f2.form_id = a.id 
JOIN Field f3 ON f3.form_id = a.id
WHERE f2.type_id = 169
AND f2.value = 'secret'
AND f3.type_id = 55
AND f3.value = 'blah'
ORDER BY a.date DESC
```

The script that creates the query can add each of these in a loop based on the search criteria.

Comment: Wow, can't believe it was that simple. It seems to work perfectly, thanks !